# How to get values from a name value pair string?

Tags: javascript, siebel

I have string variable with a value in the format of name value pair like

```
firstname:"John", lastname:"Doe", age:50,eyecolor:"blue".
```

Now, how can I get values from this string?

Comment: Do you mean that all of that is a **single** string value? If so then you will need to parse it. You could do it with regex, or perhaps wrap it in `{}` (and remove that dot) and parse it as JSON using `JSON.parse()` function

Answer (score 1):

You can create a JSON object then access the key of the object to get the desired value.

```js
var tempObj = {};
var str = 'firstname:"John", lastname:"Doe", age:50,eyecolor:"blue"';
str.split(',').forEach((item)=>{
    var key = item.split(':')[0].trim();
    var value = item.split(':')[1].replace(/"/g,'').trim();
    tempObj[key] = value;
});
console.log(tempObj);
console.log("First name is "+ tempObj.firstname);
```

Answer (score 0):

for javascript, if a single variable contains just one pair you can use `split`

```js
    const name = 'firstname:John';
    const [prop, value] = name.split(':');
    console.log(prop); //prints 'firstname'
    console.log(value); //prints 'John'
```